# Map not showing - gmaps.js - API is required

Tags: gmaps.js

I use gmaps.js to show a Maps with Google Maps.

```
new GMaps({
  div: '#map',
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333
});
```

Now the map is not showing and in the console i get the following message:

*"Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript library https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.*

I tried to do something created a Key in the Google API Console but dont know what and where to put the key i got in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simple sample for Google maps, [hope it helps](https://github.com/tym32167/googlemapsamples/blob/master/index.html#L5068)
Just before closing BODY tag, insert this

```
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
```